# Right align an element which parent might or might not have fixed width

Tags: css

I have a table which cells all contain a div-element. All of the div-elements have fixed widths. I want to right-align these divs inside the tds using css only. The problem is that not all tds have fixed width, and those without will get messed up if their child float to the right. The tds which do have fixed width are always wider than the child.
Is there anyway of doing this?
It feels a bit funny if there isn't because I can do left-align(default), and I can also do center-align by doing margin-left:auto on the child in which case divs which parents have fixed widths will center, and divs which parents dont have fixed width wont get affected. But I can't seem to find any way of right-aligning without fixing the width of all tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply doing margin-left:auto and margin-right:0(or unspecified) should do the trick.

Comment: Oh! It actually does! I was sure I tried just that dozens of times. I guess maybe there still was a margin-right somewhere that I missed. Oh well. Thanks!